# xslt send variable to another template

Tags: templates, variables, xslt

I have an xml example like this:

```
<p class="exer_header" style="display: none;">       
    <image-input size="5" value="val1" />
</p>
<p class="exer_header" style="display: none;">       
    <image-input size="5" value="val2" />
</p>
<answers-img>
    <answer-img class="imagednd_answer1" value="val1"/>
    <answer-img class="imagednd_answer2" value="val2"/>
</answers-img>
```

and XSLT ex. here:

```
<xsl:template match="image-input">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
    <xsl:element name="input">
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">exer_input</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="answers-img">
       <xsl:for-each select="//image-input"> 
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:element name="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">ans_img_input</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">hidden</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">***{ID}***</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="//answers-img/answer-img"/>                
            </xsl:element> 
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Question is next, How can I send a variable ***id*** from *"input"* template into another *"answers-img"* template and change ***{ID}***?

**UPD:** In "answer-img" I need the same **id**'s that generates in "input-img". First xslt generate code with "input-img"(twice) and when somewhere another templates, not in "input-img", call template "answer-img". Maybe I can create global array variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use xsl:with-param

I don't know where you want to call the template but it can be done like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="answers-img"><xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id" /></xsl:call-template>
```

You must add this to the calling template:

```
<xsl:param name="id" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For more details how to work with call-template and param you may visit -http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_with-param.asp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your answers-img  template is looping over image-input and you like to have the same id as is used in image-input template. In this case you can create the id the same way as you did in image-input template.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//image-input"> 
     <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
 .....
<xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:attribute>
```

This will work because generate-id() will allways create the same value for the same element.

**Update** addressing the concrete question:

How can I send a variable id from "input" template into another "answers-img" template and change {ID}?

**Answer: You can't** At least not in your example code. It is only possible to pass a value from an caller (template) to an called (template.)